# How to view the Einstein Activity Capture settings regarding its connection with Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: einstein-activity-capture

On October 1, 2022, [Microsoft is retiring](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000351807&type=1) Basic Authentication for Exchange Online. One of the ways of dealing with this is moving to Einstein Activity Capture and connect with a service account using OAuth 2.0.

The thing is, we are using a service account, but we do not know if we are connecting via Basic Authentication (which will stop working on October 1), or via OAuth2. How can we view our current settings? This is the screen and menu in Salesforce:

[image]

The available menu options look like destructive actions. It took us a lot of trouble and time to get the synchronization working, so we would like to just view the current settings, without breaking anything. How do we do that?

There is a configuration listed under the Configurations tab, but that just tells us what is synchronized and for whom.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this does not fully answer the question, but for us it was a way to find out if our configuration uses OAuth 2.0.*

We used a sandbox, in which Einstein Activity Capture had not been enabled, to start creating a connection, just to see which choices are available. These are the respective screens:

[image]

and

[image]

As you can see, only OAuth 2.0 is an option. If you choose Microsoft Exchange in the first selection, it is still possible to connect using only Basic Authentication.

As the icon in the question shows, we have a MS Office 365 connection, so we use OAuth 2.0 and the upcoming deprecation will not affect the synchronization.